# Generating websites urls in a loop on Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have a task in which I want to generate random websites URL's in a loop. The websites should be working one's and authentic. Is there any library in j-meter that can generate and add URLs in a bulk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that this is something you can "generate", you can create a **list** of existing websites i.e. from [Alexa](https://www.alexa.com/topsites) or [Big List of Websites](http://biglistofwebsites.com/).

You can even do it in JMeter, like:

1. In [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-setup-thread-group-jmeter-when-preparing-load-test/) visit alexa or big list of websites
2. Extract the URLs using a suitable JMeter [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) and write the required number of the websites to the .CSV file
3. In the main Thread Group you can read the URLs from the CSV file using [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)
4. Use the variable from the CSV data set config in the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler